# openEdx server error on exchange_access_token with azuread-oauth2

Tags: django, azure, openedx

I'm now working on deploying openEdx system and encounter an error while logging in via Azure AD from the mobile device.

The web Azure AD login is working fine and I can also get access_token from azure ad.

But, when I try to exchange azure token with openEdx token via /oauth2/exchange_access_token/azuread-oauth2/ url, I'm getting the following error due to the empty response.

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

Hence I'm fairly new to the openEdx, I have a hard time figuring out to fix the issue. Please help to direct me into the right path to fixing this issue. Following is the detail error log.

Thanks in advance

```
Apr  1 12:38:45 edxapp [service_variant=lms][django.request][env:sandbox] ERROR [edxapp  24509] [exception.py:135] - Internal Server Error: /oauth2/exchange_access_token/azuread-oauth2/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 249, in _legacy_get_response
    response = self._get_response(request)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 185, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/openedx/core/djangoapps/oauth_dispatch/views.py", line 57, in dispatch
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 67, in _wrapper
    return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 63, in bound_func
    return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 67, in _wrapper
    return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social_django/utils.py", line 49, in wrapper
    return func(request, backend, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 63, in bound_func
    return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/openedx/core/djangoapps/auth_exchange/views.py", line 44, in dispatch
    return super(AccessTokenExchangeBase, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
   File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 489, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
 File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 449, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 486, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/openedx/core/djangoapps/auth_exchange/views.py", line 57, in post
    if not form.is_valid():
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 183, in is_valid
    return self.is_bound and not self.errors
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 175, in errors
    self.full_clean()
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 385, in full_clean
    self._clean_form()
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/provider/forms.py", line 63, in _clean_form
    super(OAuthForm, self)._clean_form()
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 412, in _clean_form
    cleaned_data = self.clean()
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/openedx/core/djangoapps/auth_exchange/forms.py", line 95, in clean
    user = backend.do_auth(access_token, allow_inactive_user=True)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social_core/utils.py", line 252, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social_core/backends/oauth.py", line 410, in do_auth
    data = self.user_data(access_token, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social_core/backends/azuread.py", line 80, in user_data
    id_token = response.get('id_token')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Comment: Have you tried the [docs](https://edx.readthedocs.io/projects/edx-installing-configuring-and-running/en/latest/configuration/tpa/tpa_integrate_open/tpa_oauth.html#register-the-open-edx-instance-with-azure-active-directory) ?

Comment: yes. Already walk through these. And web login via azure is working fine. Only have this problem on the mobile azure login.

Answer (score 0):

`social-core` is throwing the error because the response is `NoneType`. It makes sense that `social-core` is responsible here as you are aiming for 3rd party oAuth2.
If it works on web, then the `None` response is explainable only if the configuration is wrong.

Now, steps to troubleshoot:

1. Check `edx.properties` to ensure that the config directory is properly set.
2. Check your `config` and `local` yamls to ensure that oauth config is proper. [instead of simply configuring `ios.yaml`]
3. Make sure you followed additional instructions provided [here](https://edx.readthedocs.io/projects/edx-installing-configuring-and-running/en/latest/configuration/tpa/tpa_integrate_open/tpa_oauth.html#register-the-open-edx-instance-with-azure-active-directory).
4. If nothing else works, check the config for `social-auth` as stated [here](https://python-social-auth-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/azuread.html).

Hope that helps! Cheers!